# Bottles with balls inside - Physics Simulation

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, rigidbody

[image: Blender]

[image: other software]

I want to create in blender a realistic physic simulation with bottles that have balls inside, first example is created Blender and the second in another 3D software.
How to create this simulation in blender? I have to checked the normals,
applied all transforms for scale, position and rotation, set Origin > origin to geometry, increasing the Steps per second and Solver Iterations in the Rigid Body World settings (I tried with the maxima 1000 and 100), set collision shape to Mesh and tried 0.4 or 0 as margins and source to final, but doesn't work..., the simulation is a mess...

I have attached here the blend file, Who can help me how to configure the rigid body settings to achieve a realistic result similar with the second example ?

Kind Regards!

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1hFKMqcwAECv01WKFnYMo5G4z8hgmvUSz

Comment: Please don't duplicate your posts! Edit the original one instead.